# Why is event.ctrlKey returning undef?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I am calling a JavaScript function when an option is selected in a select element like so:

```
<select id="select-thingy" onchange="foo(event, this); false;">
    <option value="bar">asdf</option>
...
</select>
```

The function does something like this:

```
function foo(e, elem) {
    var thingummy = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;

    alert(e.ctrlKey); // for testing only

    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

According to the alert, `e.ctrlKey` is undefined - I thought this was supposed to return either true or false? What am I missing here?

Comment: [You're quite right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.ctrlKey). Are you sure you're `e` variable is actually the event? Have you tried checking `window.event.ctrlKey`?

Comment: Yep, I've checked--I put a breakpoint right on the inside of the function and e is an Event object. 'window.event.ctrlKey' returns undefined as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MouseEvent-ctrlKey), the attribute `ctrlKey` is only available on `MouseEvent`s (like `click`, `mouseover`, etc.) but not `HTMLEvent`s.